# Can I overwrite IN parameter within a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, input, parameters, overwrite

Can I overwrite IN parameters within a MySQL stored procedure?

That is, can I do something like:

```
create procedure proc1 (IN p_parm1 int)
begin
  if p_parm1 is null then
    **set p_parm1 = -1;**
  end if
end $$
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to overwrite input parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should have tested it yourself like this:

```
mysql> create procedure proc1 (IN p_parm1 int) begin
 if p_parm1 is null then
   set p_parm1 = -1;
 end if; 
 select p_parm1;
end$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> call proc1(123)$$
+---------+
| p_parm1 |
+---------+
|     123 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call proc1(null)$$
+---------+
| p_parm1 |
+---------+
|      -1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

So the answer is yes, you can change the value of an input. In your example, you effectively give your input argument a default value in case it is null.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, my bad.

I just wasn't sure if the overwritten change would be visible to the calling environment too. I guess it won't, since its not an INOUT parameter. Anyway, as you say, I can test that too.

Usually, if I don't find a behavior explicitly documented, then I'm not comfortable inferring just based on what I happen to observe. The reason being: Well, who knows, maybe its a undocumented feature and may not be safe to rely on that.